# Avoid displaying duplicated posts on random orderby WordPress WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, random, cookies, custom-post-type

I'm setting up a news site on WordPress, I set up a query that shows the news by categories (for example: Brazil category, World category). The query is all right, and when the person clicks, the detailed news appears, as I want. However, at the base I have an option to view more news, where I set up another query, showing more news from the category.

How do I set up this second query without displaying the previous news?

For example, does it display news "A" and below it will appear news "B" and "C"?

Here's the code for how I'm setting up the second query:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    "post_type" => array("noticias"),
    "order" => "randon",
    "category_name"=>"mundo",
    "posts_per_page" => 2,
    "paged'          => $paged
); 

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your WP_Query. As you are using **"random" order by** argument, you can use **PHP cookies** to store progressively the displayed News (posts IDs), and then use those posts IDs in your query to avoid displaying them again, using `posts__not_in` argument.

You will have to use that code in your initial query too.

Note that `"order" => "randon",` does not do anything. It is `'orderby' => 'rand',` that will work for a random query. Also, `"paged'` will throw an error, to be replaced with `"paged"`.

The code (with your revisited query):

```php
// We look if our cookie exist
if( isset($_COOKIE['wp_query_news_ids']) ) {
    // cookie exist: we read it and set in the array the previous posts IDs
    $post_ids = explode(',', $_COOKIE['wp_query_news_ids']);
} else {
    $post_ids = array(); // Initializing variable
}
// The  WP query
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => array('noticias'),
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'category_name'  => 'mundo',
    'paged'          => $paged
    'orderby'        => 'rand', // <== Changed that
    'posts__not_in'  => $post_ids, // The query will not those previous posts Ids
) );

// Loop through the news (posts)
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    // We add to the array the current post ID 
    $post_ids[] = $query->post->ID; 

    // ==> Here your code that display the news

endwhile;

// We set all the displayed news IDs (posts Ids) in the cookie
setcookie('wp_query_news_ids', implode(',' ,$post_ids), time()+86400); 

wp_reset_postdata();

else:
unset($_COOKIE['wp_query_news_ids']); // Now we can remove the cookie

echo 'No more news found';
endif;
}
```

Note: PHP Cookies are compatible with caching plugins and Server caching.